# Unable to read tooltips using NVDA in IE, where as reading properly the same in chrome comfortably

Tags: javascript, nvda

I am reading tooltips using NVDA screen reader in Chrome, but it is not happening with IE. I want to read the tooltips with NVDA in Internet Explorer.

Below one is the my code:

```
 <a class="txtSmaller" href="javascript:toggleDisplay('test')" title="Showless">
View less...
</a>
```

Could someone of you please answer this question?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you use Windows 10 and IE Edge?

Comment: I am using windows 7